# Negative look-ahead matches a wrong expression in sublime text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I try to find `<img>` tag without `alt` attribute in an HTML file using **Sublime Text 3**. 
My expression: `(<img)((\s)+(?!alt)[a-z]+=\"[^>]*\")*(\s*)(>)`.

But Sublime Text anyway finds a tag with `alt` attribute. Why it doesn't work as expected? What is the right way?

`<img class="d-block retina" src="images/header/mobile/slider-bg-2_1x.jpg" alt="">` - it is found.
But I want to find something without `alt`. For example: 
`<img class="d-block retina" src="images/header/mobile/slider-bg-2_1x.jpg">`

Comment: Can you add some more sample data? Also mention what you want to match and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rejecting any `<img` tag that contains `alt` named key, you can simplify your regex to this,

```
<img\s*(?:(?!\balt=).)*\s*>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<img` - Matches start of `<img` tag
- `\s*` - Allows optional space
- `(?:(?!\balt=).)*` - This part rejects the string as soon as it sees an exact literal string like this `alt=` but allows if it sees `alt` as a substring in a larger key name like `aaaalt=` or `altxyz=` or `aaaaltbbb=` and captures any other character zero or more times
- `\s*` - Again allows optional space before end of tag
- `>` - Matches end of tag

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/05EVtN/1)**

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Glad to help :)